# django-nose nose-py3 unit test shows the string None in the output even when successful

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, nose, django-nose

1. I have installed:

   **django-nose**==1.4.7 
   **nose-py3**==1.6.3 
   **pinocchio**==0.4.3
2. added **django_nose** to the **INSTALLED_APPS**
3. added the lines:

   ```
   TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
   NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-spec', '--spec-color']
   ```

   to the settings.py file in django
4. created the following unit tests:

   ```
   def test_run_creation(self):
       """Test if the creation of runs creates instances of the Run model."""
       self.assertIsInstance(self.run1, Run)
       self.assertIsInstance(self.run2, Run)
       self.assertIsInstance(self.run3, Run)

   def test_run_number_consistency(self):
       """Test if the number of runs in the project increases by 1 after run creation."""
       self.assertEqual(self.final_no_of_runs_in_project,
                        self.initial_no_of_runs_in_project + 1)
   ```

the test run successfully and produce the following output:

```
nosetests --with-spec --spec-color --with-xunit --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

None
- Test if the creation of runs creates instances of the Run model.

None
- Test if the number of runs in the project increases by 1 after run creation.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.046s

OK

Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I would like to replace the String *None* in the output with something more descriptive but i have no idea what generate that text. Can anyone please help?

Thank you